# Example usage of HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I am aware of the `HashSet<T>.SetEquals` method, but when and how should `CreateSetComparer` be used?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475(v=vs.110).aspx) states: *"checks for equality at only one level; however, you can chain together comparers at additional levels to perform deeper equality testing"*

What would be a simple example of that?

In particular, if each item in the sets I am comparing also contains a HashSet , what would be the correct usage of `CreateSetComparer`?

Here is my starting point. I'd like to know if the `CreateSetComparer` method is applicable and how to properly use it:

```
public class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {return String.Format("{0}:{1}", Label, Value); }

    // assume for this example that Label and Value are immutable once set;
    public override int GetHashCode(){ return ToString().GetHashCode(); }
    // simplified equality check; assume it meets my needs for this example;
    public bool Equals(Foo other){ return String.Equals(this.ToString(), other.ToString()); }
}

public class FooGroup : IEquatable<FooGroup>
{
    public int GroupIndex {get; set;}
    public HashSet<Foo> FooCollection {get; set;}

    // -----------------------------
    // Does HashSet.CreateSetComparer somehow eliminate or simplify the following code?
    // -----------------------------
    public override int GetHashCode()
    { 
        int hash = GroupIndex;
        foreach(Foo f in FooCollection)
          hash = hash ^ (f.GetHashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF);
        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(FooGroup other)
    { 
        // ignore missing null checks for this example
        return this.GroupIndex == other.GroupIndex && this.FooCollection.SetEquals(other.FooCollection);
    }
}

public class GroupCollection : IEquatable<GroupCollection>
{
    public string CollectionLabel {get; set;}
    public HashSet<FooGroup> AllGroups {get; set;}

    // -----------------------------
    // Does HashSet.CreateSetComparer somehow eliminate or simplify the following code?
    // -----------------------------
    public override int GetHashCode()
    { 
        int hash = CollectionLabel.GetHashCode();
        foreach(FooGroup g in AllGroups)
          hash = hash ^ (g.GetHashCode() & 0x7FFFFFFF);
        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(GroupCollection other)
    { 
        // ignore missing null checks for this example
        return String.Equals(this.CollectionLabel, other.CollectionLabel) && this.AllGroups.SetEquals(other.AllGroups);
    }
}
```

Ignoring arguments about system design and such, a simplified use-case would be: imagine I have pulled a complex set of data that looks like this:

```
var newSetA = new GroupCollection{ ... }
var oldSetA = new GroupCollection{ ... }
```

I simply want to check:

```
if (newSetA.Equals(oldSetA))
  Process(newSetA);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a generic case where this would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the question of "when would the CreateSetComparer" be useful? You already have quite an idea here:

> In particular, if each item in the sets I am comparing also contains a HashSet , what would be the correct usage of CreateSetComparer?

Well, for example, the next example demonstrates the default behaviour when `HashSet` uses its default comparer (comparing only by references):

```
var set1 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>{
    new HashSet<int>{2,3,4},
    new HashSet<int>{7,8,9}
};
var set2 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>{
    new HashSet<int>{2,3,4},
    new HashSet<int>{7,8,9},
};

set1.SetEquals(set2).Dump(); // false :-(    
set1.SequenceEqual(set2).Dump(); // false
set1.SequenceEqual(set2, HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()).Dump(); // true
```

It's also possible to use `CreateSetComparer` with `SetEquals`, like so:

```
// the order of elements in the set has been change.
var set1 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()){
    new HashSet<int>{2,3,4},
    new HashSet<int>{7,8,9}
};
var set2 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>{
    new HashSet<int>{7,8,9},
    new HashSet<int>{2,3,4},
};

set1.SetEquals(set2).Dump(); // true :-)
set1.SequenceEqual(set2).Dump(); // false
set1.SequenceEqual(set2, HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()).Dump(); // false
```

That is the usual usage, however the `CreateSetComparer` provides `GetHashCode` which you could exploit, although this is not necessarily shorter / cleaner, what you already do.

```
// -----------------------------
// Does HashSet.CreateSetComparer somehow eliminate or simplify the following code?
// -----------------------------
private IEqualityComparer<HashSet<FooGroup>> _ecomparer = 
        HashSet<FooGroup>.CreateSetComparer();
public override int GetHashCode()
{ 
    int hash = CollectionLabel.GetHashCode();
    hash ^= _ecomparer.GetHashCode(AllGroups);
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I could not deduce this usage from the documentation. Just FYI, it caught me by surprise that SetEquals would fail with a nested set of value types...I would have thought that HashSet's behaviour of using the default comparer would have recursed in that case.

Comment: @mdisibio, I also added something about `GetHashCode`. Ps, indeed, you might argue which functionality would be more useful, but .NET philosophy is not to complicate things and ALWAYS & for everything have the same default behaviour, no exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I've used it when providing to a Dictionary with "multiple" keys in which the order does not matter:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<HashSet<int>, string>(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer());
dict[new HashSet<int> { 1, 2 }] = "foo";
dict[new HashSet<int> { 2, 1 }].Dump();
```

You can provide a nicer API by wrapping it with a `params` indexer:

```
public class MultiKeyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<HashSet<TKey>, TValue>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<HashSet<TKey>, TValue> _dict;

    public MultiKeyDictionary()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<HashSet<TKey>, TValue>(HashSet<TKey>.CreateSetComparer());
    }

    public TValue this[params TKey[] keys]
    {
        get { return _dict[new HashSet<TKey>(keys)]; }
        set { _dict[new HashSet<TKey>(keys)] = value; }
    }

    ...
}


var dict = new MultiKeyDictionary<int, string>();
dict[1, 2] = "foo";
dict[2, 1].Dump();
```